# Possible Math Error trying to find room temperature from thermistor measurements

Tags: arduino

the code below displays the resistance of a thermistor but I was wondering how to get from resistance to temperature?

```
void setup() {            
  Serial.begin(115200);   
}

void loop() {             
  int val;
  int volatge;
  val=analogRead(0); 
  float voltage= val * (5.0 / 1023.0);
  float ra= ((215000 - (voltage * 43000)) / voltage);
  Serial.println(ra);    
  delay(1000);            
}
```

Comment: Where does it return?

Comment: You should edit your question rather than posting comment, I think.

Comment: sorry Im new to coding could you explain a bit. What do you mean return?

Comment: You wrote "the code below returns -1 when it should return room temp" I would like to know what do you mean by `return` since in programming `return` is normally having its keyword written such as: `return x;`, `return -1;`, and so on. But I do not see that keyword `return` in your code. So I was wondering whether what you meant was `show` or `print` instead of `return`

Comment: I didn't mean return i mean its printing -1 when it should be printing room temp

Comment: I see... this debugging problem on microcontroller can be very difficult without proper tools. Can you use your debugger to check the value of `val` and `voltage`? If not, can you also print them out to see what values they contain? `Serial.println(val);` and `Serial.println(voltage);` If all these show -1, then the problem lies somewhere else with possibly data obtaining from micro-controller or with incorrect Serial Port initialization, for instance. In any case, try to debug by checking the value of val and voltage first

Comment: i get the expected values of serial.println(ra) which is dependent on val and voltage so they must be correct

Comment: The datasheet will tell you how to get from resistance to temperature. As you have not provided a datasheet or a part number, this question is difficult to answer.

Comment: I do not have a data sheet or part number all I know is its a 10 k-ohm resistor